# organize sql heirarchy

Tags: sql, t-sql, hierarchy

I have the following table:

```
Id   Son  RowOrder   Technology
1     8     NULL       fa
8     0     NULL       fa
9     15    NULL       gr
15    0     NULL       gr
```

I would like to create an sql query that will do an "order by" by the following
order: technology, "father" (a record that has a son), son (the direct son of the previous father"
and do an update to the RowOrder column so next time i will order these records sole based on the RowOrder.
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: why do you want to do this update? why not always order by technology, father, son ? It will get you the same results but if you do updates to put numbers in RowOrder then you will need to run that update every time you insert, update or delete a record to make sure it is still correct.

Comment: the list isn't supposed to change, only the order will change by the user. so i'll create an interface to update the RowOrder column but this initial query is the way i want to show the results the first time the user sees them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want data to change then instead of storing the data in row number just use

```
SELECT 
   id,
   son, 
   technology,
   ISNULL((select id from table t2 where t2.id = t1.son), 0) AS father,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY technology, father, son) AS RowNumber
FROM 
   table t1 
ORDER BY 
   RowNumber ASC
```

the functions ISNULL() and ROW_NUMBER() may change name depending on what database you are using but that is a rough idea of what you should go for.

Comment: good idea martyn, I tweaked it a bit. I added the column "Father", and changed the order of son to descending in the "order by" in the Row_Number() clause. so now I have this:ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY technology, father, son desc) AS RowNumber. and it's working so thanks.